# regression coefficients: changing the scale of the independent variables?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, scale, coefficients

I'm running a weighted regression model, but I have no idea how to deal with some variable that I need to put inside

My dependent variable has values with a scale of thousands, while my independent variables have scale of tens and hundreds or are categorical variables.

I usually run the regression with the log of the dependent variable ( in this way I can interpret the estimated coefficient as % increase )

Here an example

[image: regression]

How to handle instead with a variable between the regressors that has a scale of millions ?

For example, I include in my regression the variable `occ_tot` expressed in millions. This is what happens

[image: regression 2]

How should I interpret these coefficients? Is there a nice way to include an independent variable with a bigger scale of the dependent one?

I'm new with these kind of things...

Comment: This is a question about data modeling and not about programming. You should ask for help at [stats.se] rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: maybe i am missing something in your question, the coef in the 2 models are somewhat stable exp for sex 0.27 eta 5*10-3 ... in the 2 models (note sex should be factorized)

Comment: @Wael sex is a dummy, why should I factorized?

Comment: @io_boh, ok then it wasn't clear that sex was dummy,  could you explain more your question ? your problem was the outcome (tpens) log transformed or not or the features adding occ_tot to the model.
as suggested by MrFlick Cross Validated is more adapted for your question

Comment: @Wael the point is that the variable `occ_tot` has values like 1889272, 6784213 or 9874562 etc, while the endogenous variable `tpens` has only values like 1654, 1200, 1330. If I put the variable `occ_tot` on the right side of the regression  I get very very small values for the coefficients and I have no idea how to interpret them. If instead the regressors have the same scale of the endogenous variable, you get coefficient with a magnitude of 0.30 or 0.21 etc. If you use the log for the dependent variable these coefficient of 0.30 and 0.21 can be interpreted as the 30% or 21%.

Comment: The problem is  in case `occ_reg` is in the regression, because you get  0.27 eta 5*10-3 as coefficient ( due to its scale). Is there a way to put this variable in the regression and get estimates as 0.32 or 0.10 rather than the one with eta??

Comment: @Wael i hope i was able to explain myself

Comment: it is better to migrate your question to Cross Validate

Comment: @Wael i've already tried to ask there... but that forum seems to be dead. Nobody answer... it is not only about my question, but almost about all the questions there

Comment: @Wael i'm thinking to include the variable `occ_reg` dividing it by 100, in this way its scale would be in line with the other regressors... Do you think is a bad thing?

Comment: You can scale any column whose regression coefficient is much smaller or larger than the others but quite frequently this is mainly a problem with nonlinear regression.  Linear regression tends to be more robust to scale although there may exist counter examples.

Comment: hi @G.Grothendieck and thanks for the answer! To be sure that i've understand your message:  you are telling me that I don't do anything  wrong if i enter these values divided by 100 in the regression, right?

Comment: Have responded in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can scale a predictor as desired and normally the coefficients will simply compensate so that if we multiply a predictor by 100 the corresponding coefficient will get divided by 100 and visa versa while the other coefficients will not be affected.

If some predictors are close to linearly dependent one can run into problems but that is the case even without scaling so that is really a separate problem.  Look at `findCorrelation` in caret to eliminate highly correlated predictors and try it with and without eliminating such predictors to see if it matters in your case.

The first `lm` below is our original regression.  In the second `lm` we multiply the `wt` predictor by 100 and we see that the coefficient simply gets divided by 100 and the other coefficients stay the same.  A similar thing happens with the third `lm` where we divide by 100 and the coefficient compensates again while the other coefficients are again unchanged.

Also note that all three of these are really the same model except for parameterization so they result in the same fitted values, the same residuals and the same residual sum of squares.

```
coef(lm(mpg ~ cyl + wt, mtcars))  # original lm
## (Intercept)         cyl          wt 
##   39.686261   -1.507795   -3.190972 

coef(lm(mpg ~ cyl + I(100 * wt), mtcars))
## (Intercept)         cyl I(100 * wt) 
## 39.68626148 -1.50779497 -0.03190972

coef(lm(mpg ~ cyl + I(wt/100), mtcars)) 
## (Intercept)         cyl   I(wt/100) 
##   39.686261   -1.507795 -319.097214
```

If we have a log predictor then changing `wt` to `100*wt` will only affect the intercept because `log(100 * wt)` = `log(100) + log(wt)`.  Below the first `lm` we take `log(wt)` and in the second one we take `log(100*wt)`.

```
coef(lm(mpg ~ cyl + log(wt), mtcars))
## (Intercept)         cyl     log(wt) 
##   40.649777   -1.233526  -11.523812 
 
coef(lm(mpg ~ cyl + log(100 * wt), mtcars))
## (Intercept)           cyl log(100 * wt) 
##   93.718894     -1.233526    -11.523812
```

Comment: you have no idea how helpful you have been. I've founded out that I had correlated variables and you have made clear how to handle the scientific notation in the coefficients ! Thank you very much